# nesting and unnesting

Tags: mysql, sql, string-aggregation

I have a table like below

```
name                value
-----        |      ------
rami         |      2
rami         |      3
rami         |      4

sam                 5
sam                 6
```

I want to piviot it in a way to get this result

```
Rami      sam
-----     -----
2,3,4     5,6
```

Comment: Please. Before posting verify the preview. What's more, show your efforts, your research, where you bump into an issue, and describe that particular aspect. Also tag which database engine you are using.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: THANK YOUMYSQL AS DBMS

Answer (score 1):

You need here a somewhat more complicated pivot table

the user defined variable @sql get the names and add the values
The outer select is made by @sql2

> ```
> CREATE TABLE name_val
>     (`name` varchar(4), `value` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO name_val
>     (`name`, `value`)
> VALUES
>     ('rami', 2),
>     ('rami', 3),
>     ('rami', 4),
>     ('sam', 5),
>     ('sam', 6)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = NULL;
> SET @sql2 = NULL;
> SELECT
>   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>                CONCAT('GROUP_CONCAT(IF(s.`name` = "', `name`,'", `value`,"")) AS ',name)
>               ) INTO @sql
> FROM name_val;
> SELECT
>   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>                CONCAT('MAX(', `name`,') AS ',name)
>               ) INTO @sql2
> FROM name_val;
>
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ',@sql2,' FROM (SELECT ', @sql, ' 
>                   FROM name_val s
>                  GROUP BY s.`name`
>                  ORDER BY s.`name`) t1');
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> rami  | sam
> :---- | :--
> 2,3,4 | 5,6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b860248c37d819f57ffb8a605ebd898)*

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select group_concat(case when name = 'Rami' then value end order by value) as rami,
       group_concat(case when name = 'Sam' then value end order by value) as sam
from t;
```